# Импорт куки youtube selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Пытаюсь импортировать куки youtube в браузер. (Наверное стоит уточнить, что я использую undetected_chromedriver)
Все как полагается, перехожу на домен [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com), сортирую и форматирую куки из netscape формата в json, driver.add_cookie(cookie) и все, мрак. Ни при каких обстоятельствах не хочет импортировать куки. Пробовал множество разных форматов, например: {name: value}
Сейчас остановился на таком, ведь сам селениум возвращает их в таком виде, да и должен принимать тоже.

```
cookie={
 'name':cookie_line[5],
 'value':cookie_line[6],
 'domain': cookie_line[0],
 'expires': int(cookie_line[4]),
 'path': cookie_line[2],
 'httpOnly': True if cookie_line[1] == "TRUE" else False,
 'Secure': True if cookie_line[3] == "TRUE" else False
}
```

В результате выдает selenium.common.exceptions.UnableToSetCookieException: Message: unable to set cookie
Какие могут быть пути решения?